# How to control a brushed DC (ish) motor. Is because it's just 110V AC passed thru a full wave bridge rectifier

Tags: motor-controller

I have a hoist in my home shop with a 12.5A 1500W 110V brushed DC motor.  The kind of DC I described in the title.

I see two rectifiers in the system.  I want to control the speed (slow it way down) and ideally have a little ramp in and out built in to the controller output. I'd like to not sacrifice too much power so it still has plenty of lifting potential. Ideally it wouldn't be physically too large, say, smaller than a soda can. Can anyone steer me towards the right kind of hardware I can ideally buy (possibly could build) and where in the system to insert it?

I should mention that the hoist has a wireless handset and receiver so I don't want to just plug the whole hoist into some device since the electronics for the receiver might not work well at diminished or manipulated voltage. I'm an electrician, with very minimal understanding of electronics, so please tailor your answer to a beginner.

Update:

Here are a couple pics of the hoist. I do have an extra trolly that could be the attachment point for a block and tackle system. Maybe that in combination with some electronic controlling will solve the equation. Interestingly, as we add pulleys, we double/quadruple the effective weight lifting capacity of the hoist, offsetting losses in torque associated with some of these electronic slowing techniques. As for jogging, it's my current technique and it's quite choppy. There is a mechanical brake in the gearbox, as I understand. Also, the hoist does short lifts for a limited duration, so heat could be not so much of a concern, within limits.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Something like these: https://www.ohioelectricmotors.com/2015/07/dc-motors-used-in-electric-hoists-reels-and-winches/

Answer (score 2):

To control the speed without going to the trouble of using a variable DC power supply, you can use:

- Standard triac phase cut dimmer (for inductive loads) before the rectifier. This is simple, it works, it's what is used in most AC powered drills, vacuum cleaners, etc. However the motor power is chopped at 120Hz so you get a lot of torque ripple and it has pretty bad control at low speed and tends to have a "jerky" start. If you tried to use a mains powered drill as a power screw driver, you'll see what I mean. That's the "cheap and nasty" solution.
- PWM with a MOSFET after the rectifier. This simply chops the DC voltage at a much higher frequency. It doesn't matter if the DC voltage is actually rectified AC. This has much better control over the speed, especially at low speed. Since it is possible to turn off a MOSFET, this can also set a maximum current (thus a maximum torque) or even regulate speed, but you'll need a speed sensor and more complicated circuitry for this.

You say you want to "control the speed (slow it way down)" and "not sacrifice too much power so it still has plenty of lifting potential" which I take as meaning you want to keep a high torque. So, make it slower to accurately position whatever you're lifting, but still lift a heavy load.

Problem is, with a motor, torque is proportional to current, so if you use a simple speed controller, at low speed you'll have low current and low torque too.

You could use a controller that regulates current and thus torque. That works fine on a RC car, but it won't work on a hoist, because a hoist is a lot more "binary": either the torque is enough to lift the load, or it is not. There's no point in having fine control of torque in the range where there isn't enough of it to lift the load.

So it would work much better with a circuit that regulates speed, and sets the speed to whatever you want, adjusting current automatically. But this is more complicated. This needs a speed sensor. You could try to find a motor speed controller for a DC motor of this voltage. How to adapt it to your remote is another question.

There's also the problem that these DC motors don't have good efficiency outside of their preferred RPM range, so slowing a motor down a lot will usually make it overheat. In addition, the slower it goes, the less the fan blows, so it heats even more. The usual solution is a gearbox to get the speed you want while having the motor work at the rpm it wants.

Since the output of this hoist is a cable, why not just use [pulleys](https://myslide.ru/presentation/skachat-vantazhopidjomni-mashini-derzhgirpromnaglyad) instead? You can get a 2 or 4 times reduction in speed with simple hardware, and the motor will still run at its optimum rpm.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One way to slow it down without losing torque *might* be to jog it, with perhaps 1/2 second on and 1 second off. You could try it first by manually jogging it, and if results are satisfactory, a simple interval timer could be used to control a solid state AC relay (triac or SCR). However, this might be noisy and the rapid on/off may cause problems with the gear train, especially for a heavy load. The strain could be minimized by using an elastic rope or spring.

It might be necessary to short the windings of the motor when stopped, to act as a brake, or there may be an actual friction brake in the controller, so that might complicate matters. Some pictures of the hoist and the existing controller would help a lot.